# Battery drainage is pretty high

Tags: battery, battery-life

[image]Ok so, my screen battery draining stats is 122%, Android system 52%, Android OS 27%, Media Servers 25%, and suprising ly my games 25% or below. How to fix this? Cause if you combine all the percentages in my Android Lollipop 5.0.2 tablet,(It is a Samsung Tab 4, and it is NOT rooted). it would be over 300% battery drain stats. So... again, how do I fix this?

Edit: Every minute a play: -3% battery percentage on average.

[image]

Comment: It looks like Android mess up. Suggest flash  ROM again after taking backup. Also add to your question details of device, Android version and root status

Answer (score 1):

If you watch closely you will see it states: Use since full charge. This means it counts from the time the battery was at 100%. Charge your device to 100% and the numbers will be fine...